# How to add il.h path from Devil to CMakeList

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, cmakelists-options, devil

I need to use Devil for a school project and im having a bit of trouble.

The  `#include <IL/il.h>`  says 'IL/il.h' file not found, so im trying to add the .h path to CMakeList.

I install Devil with homebrew and add the following to CMakeList:

`include_directories(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/devil/1.8.0_3/include/IL)`

And

`add_executable(IL/il.h)`

But i get this error:

`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_executable): The target name "IL/il.h" is reserved or not valid for certain CMake features, such as generator expressions, and may result in undefined` `behavior.`

Comment: `add_executable(IL/il.h)` is not an executable. Remove that line.

Comment: `include_directories(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/devil/1.8.0_3/include/IL)` probably should be `include_directories(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/devil/1.8.0_3/include)` unless you actually have a `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/devil/1.8.0_3/include/IL/IL` folder. Remember the `IL/il.h` path will be relative to the folders specified as include directories.

Comment: @drescherjm I remove the add_executable line and modify the include_directories to only /include, it works! Thank u

Comment: You don't need to add headers as sources to a target. It's convenient to do so, if the headers belong to the target itself, e.g. Visual Studio lists them among the soures in that case, but usually you don't add headers of external libs. Furthermore usually `target_include_directories` should be preferred to `include_directories`.